# Nautilus icon positions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nautilus

I'm looking for where Nautilus stores the icon positions on a Ubuntu 10.10 system. I would like to back-up this information in case it's lost somehow, and possibly programatically manipulate this information.

All information I've found seems to indicate that the information has been migrated to gvfs's metadata stores. Is there a way to query/modify this information, and where is it stored?

Comment: What kind of icon's position are we talking about? Is it the icon which appears in the panel?

Comment: You might get better answers on Stack Overflow's sibling [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Comment: Yes, icons in the panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the metadata stored with gvfs using *gvf-info*.  Probably you might want to read some of the decisions taken in a [blog post from Alexander Larsson: "Data about data"](http://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2009/06/24/data-about-data/).